# PHP parses XML content without looping the hyperlink

Tags: php

I have an xml file structured like this:

```
<channel>
 <title>abc</title>
 <link>domain.com</link>
 <description>Bla bla.</description>
<item>
  <title>xyz </title>
  <link>domain.com/</link>
<description>
  <table border="1" width="100%"><tr><th colspan="2"></th><th>P</th><th>W</th><th>D</th><th>L</th><th>GF</th><th>GA</th><th>Dif</th><th>Pts</th></tr><tr><td width="7%">1</td><td width="27%"><a target="_blank" href="domain[dot]com/new-york/"/>New York</td><td width="7%"><center>12</center></td><td width="7%"><center>8</center></td><td width="7%"><center>2</center></td><td width="7%"><center>2</center></td><td width="7%"><center>17</center></td><td width="7%"><center>10</center></td><td width="7%"<center>+7</center></td><td width="7%"><center>26</center></td></tr><tr><td width="7%">2</td><td width="27%"><a target="_blank" href="domain[dot]com/lon-don/"/>London</td><td width="7%"><center>12</center></td><td width="7%"><center>6</center></td><td width="7%"><center>4</center></td><td width="7%"><center>2</center></td><td width="7%"><center>22</center></td><td width="7%"><center>12</center></td><td width="7%"><center>+10</center></td><td width="7%"><center>22</center></td></tr></table><br/>
</description>
```

I used this piece of code to parse the `table data` in PHP and i was successful:

```
$url = "link to the above xml file";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){

    $desc = html_entity_decode((string)$item->description);
    $descXML = simplexml_load_string('<desc>'.$desc.'</desc>');
    $html = $descXML->table->asXML();
    $html .= "<hr />";          
    echo $html;
}
```

However, it also includes the hyperlink in the `table data`/ `array values`, which are `domain[dot]com/newyork/` and `domain[dot]com/london/` while outputting.

What I am expecting is that I would like to `exclude the hyperlinks` in the output, which means that I just need the plain text such as `Lon Don` or `New York` and so on.

No hyperlink in the output, please.

Thanks,

Comment: `<a target="_blank" href="domain[dot]com/new-york/"/>` <- why is that anchor a self-closing tag rather than a normal HTML `<a>` tag that wraps the text? e.g. `<a target="_blank" href="domain[dot]com/new-york/">New York</a>`

Comment: Since the `<description>` element seems to be holding HTML data - it's probably best not to use ancient, defunct tags like `<center>`

Comment: @CD001 if we do `$html_arr =  (explode(" ",$html));//Put into array 
  print_r($html_arr);` , we will see it like that.

Comment: Why are you even exploding it? You're chucking it into a parser (SimpleXML) so you shouldn't need to deal with any string manipulation...

Comment: @CD001 Okay, so forget about the `explode` function. Just go back to the `echo $html` itself, and please help me to exclude the `links`. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are just displaying the entire table XML in

```
$html = $descXML->table->asXML();
```

This contains all of the markup of the table, what you need to do if you just want some of the table data is to further process it to extract that data...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->item as $item){

     $desc = html_entity_decode((string)$item->description);
     $descXML = simplexml_load_string('<desc>'.$desc.'</desc>');
     // Loop over each row of the table
     foreach ( $descXML->table->tr as $row ) {
        // If there are td elements
        if ( isset($row->td) )  {
            // Extract the value from the second td element, convert to a string and trim the result
            $html = trim((string)($row->td[1]));
            $html .= "<hr />";
            echo $html;

        }
    }
}
```

If you want all of the `<tr>` XML except the `<a>` tag, you can just unset it (assuming it will always be there)...

```
     foreach ( $descXML->table->tr as $row ) {
        // If there are td elements
        if ( isset($row->td) )  {
            unset($row->td[1]->a);
            $html = $row->asXML(). "<hr />";
            echo $html;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. and what if we need all the td elements, but just the second one without the `links`? BTW, the foreach loop should look like this `foreach($xml->**channel**->item as $item){...`